# Showing stages in loaded scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I want to integrate a specific pipeline into a more general one. The generic one parses email notifications and checks out a project from a specific SCM. At this point it runs the Jenkinsfile found in that project.
Both of these are scripted pipelines.

**generic.jenkinsfile:**

```
node {
  stage('Initial') {
      echo 'Checking for new RRs and creating build sandbox'
  }

  stage('Calling specific') {
      def jen = load "../specific.jenkinsfile"
  }

  stage('Cleanup') {
      echo 'running cleanup'
  }
}
```

**specific.jenkinsfile:**

```
node() {
  stage('Build') {
      echo 'Build ...'          
  }
  stage('Flash ') {
      echo 'Flash ...'          
  }
  stage('Test  ') {    
      echo 'Test  ...'    
  }
}
```

The steps in the stages in the specific.jenkinsfile does run and print the steps.
The problem is that the stages in the specific Jenkinsfile does not show up as individual stages on the build overview page on the BlueOcean web-interface. Instead the *Calling specific* accumulates all of the steps after the `load` step returns. (While the `load` is running the stages are all "expanded" side-by-side.) This doesn't happen on the classic interface. Maybe this is a design decision?

[image: View on BlueOcean]
[image: View on classic]

How can I make it to show all of them expanded in BlueOcean just like on the classic site?

Comment: Unfortunately that not possible. You are trying to print the stages of your subjob into your main job. You can just show the steps in the logs instead of actual stages in the UI

Comment: Accidentally I found out, that on the old site the "subjobs" are visible, just as I wanted. And in BlueOcean these jobs are also visible until the caller stage (with the load step) returns. So far I haven't found an issue for this feature on the blueocean issue tracker.

Comment: just found a plugin , i posted the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is easier than I expected.

I removed the `stage('Calling specific') {}` from around the `load` step, and the `node {}` from the specific.jenkinsfile. Now the visualization is behaves as desired.

```
# scripted pipeline
node {
  stage('Initial') {
    echo 'Checking for new RRs and creating build sandbox'
  }

  def jen = load "../specific.jenkinsfile"

  stage('Cleanup') {
    echo 'running cleanup'
  }
}
```